# Can't get Protobuf-net working with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, protobuf-net

I recently tried Protobuf-net r668 with my vb.net code. I can mark attributes on my data class but can't get the Serialize and Deserialize features to work.
I followed the instructions at http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted but having converted the code to vb.net I found that this C# code:

```
using (var file = File.Create("person.bin")) {
    Serializer.Serialize(file, person);
}
```

Won't work when translated to vb.net because the Serialize method does not show up as a method of class Protobuf.Serializer.

Any pointers from anyone who has got Protobuf-net working in vb.net would be helpful.

Comment: What platform are you targeting? If this is regular .NET, this should simply work fine - it is a regular static method, nothing remarkable or unusual. Are you perhaps targeting windows phone or similar?

Comment: I am developing on Windows 7, 64 bit, with Visual Studio 2010. I am using .net Framework 4.

Comment: but what platform are you *targeting*? regular .NET? or one of the mobile platforms?

Comment: Sorry, target platform is .net framework 4, if you are referring to the Advanced Compile Options.

Comment: ah, I wonder; do you perhaps have a type, field, variable, property etc in your own code called `Serializer`? I wonder if the compiler is simply choosing your local declaration...

Comment: This gives error "Serialize is not a member of Protobuf.Serializer"      Dim f As FileStream = File.Create(strFileName)
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(f, objData)

Comment: I think you're used the "core only" build. Basically: don't! Use the full build. That version is intended for specific use-cases of which yours is not one ;p As odd as this might sound, the static `Serialize` method is not part of the core-only build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work; the following runs fine, for example:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim strFileName As String = "foo.bin"
        Dim f As FileStream = File.Create(strFileName)
        Dim objData As Foo = New Foo With {.Name = "abcdef"}
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(f, objData)
    End Sub

    <ProtoBuf.ProtoContract>
    Class Foo
        <ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)>
        Property Name As String
    End Class
End Module
```

My initial thought is that you have referenced a version of the protobuf-net.dll that is intended for one of the mobile platforms, which expose some features slightly differently. Specifically, a dll from the "core only" build. The intended purpose of each different build is described in the [`What Files Do I Need.txt`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/What%20Files%20Do%20I%20Need.txt) file (which is include in the root of the package)

Comment: Thanks Marc! You were right, I grabbed the core only build by mistake. I swapped DLLs and the vb.net code runs fine now.

Comment: Also want to add that it is blazingly faster than the .net serialization... thanks a lot.

Comment: @stackmike_2014 To put that in perspective, I'm working on something that should, in theory, be much much faster than protobuf-net ;p

Comment: I can't wait. I discovered protobuf-net a week ago when I was unhappy with .net taking 10-12 seconds to deserializer a 65 MB savestate file for some of my data structures. With some test cases I've done today, I suspect protobuf will cut that to less than half the time... once I've added in attributes everywhere. Keep coding Marc, and thank you.